# Which field is causing: "Unable to read SObject's field value[s]"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, error-messages

I know this error is because there is a wrong data type, but I feel that I have validation on all my input fields. I have had this error 3 or 4 times over the past year with customers and am at a loss as to where it is coming from. Is there a way to determine what field is throwing this error? Is there any server side logging I can setup? Or do I need to log the whole payload next time it happens and manually inspect it?

Comment: Unable to read SObject's field value[s] error occurs when we send the wrong type value for the fields or not sending the sobjectType in the object param.

Example: sending text value for number type field. This also could happen with an invalid date format for example (20/14/201 ) so It's hard to check which field is causing the issue unless you can reproduce it on demand. You need to log the whole payload to locate the field as far as I know

Comment: That is unfortunate, but what I expected. Thank you

Comment: Posting this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to read SObject's field value[s] error occurs when we send the wrong type value for the fields or not sending the sobjectType in the object param. Example: sending text value for number type field. This also could happen with an invalid date format for example (20/14/201 ) so It's hard to check which field is causing the issue unless you can reproduce it on demand. You need to log the whole payload to locate the field as far as I know